# Find the greatest and least values for $|z - w|$ for points on these loci.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

So I'm given that
$$ |z - (-i)| = 1$$
and $$arg(w - 2) = \frac{3\pi}{4}$$

I have plotted the loci. The first is the circumference of a circle with center -i and radius 1, and the second is a half-line starting at -2 and making the given angle with the positive real axis.

Now, my next question is:
Find the greatest and least values for $|z - w|$ for points on these loci.

I am having trouble understanding what $|z - w|$ means. So z is an arbitrary complex number on the circle, right? And w is an arbitrary complex number on the half-line?

If that is so, does $|z - w|$ mean the "magnitude of of z minus the magnitude of w"?

And if that is so, isn't the least value for   $|z - w|$ going to be from the origin to -2? And what of the greatest?

I wish I could attach a sketch or something, but I can't (I also hope my half-line is correct -- it starts at $-2$).

Comment: Isn’t your ray supposed to be at +2 on the real axis? Clarify, someone?

Comment: @Mathematician Yes, the ray would start at $2$, not $-2$.

Comment: Can someone tell me why? How do I know?

Comment: @Alpha A way to think about subtraction is that it shifts your frame of reference: given $f(w-a)$ for some function $f$ and a constant $a$, it's when $w=a$ that we have $f(0)$, i.e., $a$ is the "new origin". Try plugging in $w=2$ vs. $w=-2$ in your function $\arg(w-2)$ to see what happens. Compare to a function like $f(x)=(x-1)^2$: the vertex of this parabola is at $x=1$, not $x=-1$. For exactly the same reason, your circle is centred at $-i$ (as you correctly stated), not at $i$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close. If you have points $z$ and $w$, then $z-w$ is the vector pointing from $w$ to $z$. This makes $|z-w|$ the length of the line segment between those two points. Your guess of "the magnitude of $z$ minus the magnitude of $w$" would be $|z|-|w|$, which is a different animal. Note that since $|\cdot|$ is always non-negative, the least value of $|z-w|$ cannot be $-2$.

In particular, given your two curves, the smallest value of $|z-w|$ would be the length of the smallest line segment between those curves.

---

Side comment: here are a couple of terminology tips that will save you a few words. Instead of "circumference of a circle", you can just call it a *circle*. A "filled circle" would be a *disc*. Second, a "half-line" is a *ray*.

Comment: I see. So, after thinking about it, is the least distance going to be from the point (2,0) to the circle, perpendicular to the circle? If that's so, I found the equation of the line that passes through (2, 0) to be $ y = 0.5x - 1$. Then I reasoned I should formulate an equation for the circle, and substitute the line for y into it. I did not get the correct answer. What am I supposed to do?

Comment: The answer is in exact form and I *can't* use a calculator in the question. Is the method I detailed above (if correct) the most efficient way? How is this problem typically done?

Comment: @Alpha Notice that the line you found is not perpendicular to the ray. It doesn't necessarily need to pass through $(2,0)$. It does need to pass through the centre of the circle, though, so you draw a line from $0-i$ to the ray such that it hits the ray at a right angle.